# Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'NoneType'> python-django

Tags: python, django

I have a issue on read excel file uploaded by user,here my code

```
 if request.method == 'GET':
        add_file = request.FILES.get('monthly_file')
        df = pd.read_excel(add_file)
```

When i give `request.Files['monthly_file]` it gave ***multidict key value error***,. So im using `request.FILES.get('monthly_file')` to get user uploaded file. But it gives Invalid file path or buffer object type: `<class 'NoneType'>` value error,. How can i resolve it..
Thanks in advance,..

Comment: Shouldnt it be for the POST request rather than GET ?

Comment: if i give POST it didnot  come inside post request. I dontknow why it accept get request..

Comment: if the below posted answer not work, please add your form in the question...

Comment: Hello @VijiLakshmi make sure you've form tag like this ``<form  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">`` and you;ve put name to your input tag

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have used the POST method in forms and similarly you recieve the file on the POST method of your views...

**Template.html**

```
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <!-- OTHER FORM FIELDS -->
    <input type="submit" VALUE = "SUBMIT">
</form>
```

**VIEWS.PY**

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    try:
        add_file = request.FILES.get('monthly_file')
        df = pd.read_excel(add_file)
    except:
        print('NO FILE FOUND')
```